# Replace string of 'X' with space do not want to remove 'X' if it occur in a word

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I Replace trail of 'X' or single 'X' with space? I don't want to remove single 'X' if it occurs in a word?

```
**INPUT**: 'This is X XXXXXXXXXXX my SXTRINGXXXX'

**OUTPUT** 'This is     my SXTRING '
```

I have tried below query to get the output:

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(100) = 'THIS IS X XXXXXXXXXXX MY SXTRINGXXXX'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@D,'XXX','='),'=XX','='),'=X','='),'=',' '),'XX',''),' X ',' ')
```

Please suggest other optimised option.

Comment: Use a regex - that is the optimal solution. I gather the basic rule is "remove X's, except a single X that is attached to another alphabetic character on at least one side, or a series of X's attached to another character on both sides". There are no dictionary English words with more than one X in series, but there may be exceptions in general language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by doing this

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@D,'XXX','='),'=XX','='),'=X','='),'=',' '),'XX',''),' X ',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo = 1,
        xStr = CAST('THIS IS X XXXXXXXXXXX MY SXTRINGXXXX' AS VARCHAR(255))

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        SeqNo = CHARINDEX('XX',xStr),
        xStr = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(xStr,'XX',''),'X X','') AS VARCHAR(255))
        FROM CTE
            WHERE SeqNo > 0
)
SELECT
    xStr = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(xStr,'  ',' ')))
    FROM CTE
        WHERE SeqNo = 0
```